# Storing arraylist in a mysql database using JPA

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, arraylist

I am trying to add an arraylist of double values to my mysql database using JPA and Hibernate but it is not storing the values as doubles, it is storing the arraylist object and then a lot of characters.

The image below is what the database looks like.

[Arraylist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTFRl.jpg)

Here's my code:

Playlist.java

```
@Entity
public class Playlist {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
private int id;

private String name, persistentId;
private double playlistId;
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name ="tracks")
private ArrayList<Double> tracks = new ArrayList<Double>();

@OneToMany(mappedBy="playlist") 
Set<Song> songs;

public Playlist(String name, String persistentId, double playlistId, ArrayList<Double> tracks) {
    this.name = name;
    this.persistentId = persistentId;
    this.playlistId = playlistId;
    this.tracks = tracks;
}

public Playlist() {
}
```

Main.java

```
Playlist p = new Playlist();
ArrayList<Double> tracks = new ArrayList<Double>();
        for (int j = 0; j < tList.getLength(); ++j) {
            Element track = (Element) tList.item(j);

            Double trackId = (Double) x.evaluate("key[.='Track ID']/following-sibling::integer[1]", track,
                    XPathConstants.NUMBER);
            tracks.add(trackId);
            p.setTracks(tracks);

        }
```

Could anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: @NeilStockton I wanted to show that because it shouldn't look like that. It should show number values.

Comment: Why not start by providing the DEFINITION of the DDL for the tables in the datastore rather than that??? so then you see has it mapped the DB correctly. If it has created a BLOB for that column then Hibernate has got it wrong at the outset, so concentrate on your mapping rather than persistence code. Also post what type is "ArrayList" ... java.util ? then look at the log of your JPA implementation to see why it is mapping it to a BLOB (incorrectly)

Answer (score 1):

Try to set more informations :

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name ="tracks" , joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="playlist_id"))
@Column(name="track")
private List<Double> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: No unfortunately it's saying the same as the above comment "1183 [main] INFO org.hibernate.cfg.search.HibernateSearchEventListenerRegister - Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled.
"..."Could not determine type for: java.util.List, at table: Playlist, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(track)]"

Comment: It had to create a table not a blob in the documentation, maybe regenerate the schema. Try to use a Set in place List.

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping a specific implementation of the `List` interface. Hibernate uses it's own implementation, so my guess is that it gets thrown off by this. Quite strange that it doesn't fail hard though..

Try changing it to:

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name ="tracks")
private List<Double> tracks = new ArrayList<>();
```

(The `new ArrayList<>()` part is just for making it null-safe..)

Comment: Nope I'm getting an error saying "Unable to find org.hibernate.search.event.FullTextIndexEventListener on the classpath. Hibernate Search is not enabled." when I change that.

Comment: What are the database column types in the `tracks` table?

Comment: JPA creates the column as a tinyblob but I have to change it to a longblob to store the data I need.

Comment: That sounds incorrect, the expected here would be a table named `tracks` with a reference to the owner table, and a column for storing `Double` values (numeric or something like that..)